# How to measure Common Mode Range and Output Swing of a CMOS Differential Amplifier in LTspice

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, cmos, differential-amplifier

I'm designing a CMOS opamp in LTspice here is my current design.

[image]

The amplifier obtains a DC gain of roughly 50dB and has a phase margin of 70 degrees at a ω (unity gain frequency) = 250 MHz. I'm also using a 32nm process technology with [this BSIM library file](https://file.io/G534p7iJmbmQ).

I'm wondering specically how to calculate the input common mode range and the peak to peak output swing of my amplifier. My guess for the output swing would be to step in input value and see the possible range of outputs.

[image]

Running a DC operating point simulation I see the ouput can vary by around 0.87V

[image]

Would the input common mode range then be the range of inputs that bring the ouput from it's min to max i.e

[image]
(about 0.5V)

Normally I would compute input and and output ranges based on the saturation contion of the devices in the circuit. I don't have much experience working with spice and I'm wondering how I can do it exactly in my simulation.

Thanks

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you should be using 4-terminal MOSFETs in simulating IC designs, i.e. the `nmos4` and `pmos4` symbols. Then tie the nmos bodies to VSS while the pmos bodies goes to VDD.  M1 and M2 are currently not connected correctly because you're using the 3-terminal symbols which short body and source together.

Comment: @SteKulov Is this bad? Doesn't tying the bulk to the source get rid of any body effect?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-041.pdf)?

Comment: @user2757771 Not always bad, but that's not how ICs are constructed. A typical CMOS process is built on a p-substrate which is connected to VSS. NMOS transistors use this substrate as its "body". The PMOS transistors are built on top of "n-wells" carved out of the substrate to form their "bodies". You can technically connect each n-well to whatever you want, but they're typically connected to VDD. The reason CMOS IC schematics only show three terminals is because these assumptions are already previously established. They'll explicitly show the 4-th terminal if they want it connected elsewhere.

Comment: @user2757771  See here for more info: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/414394/ic-layouts-transistors-body